# Fast Fourier Transform and Time-Series Forecasting in R

Tags: r, time-series, fft, continuous-fourier

After reviewing the literature available for FFT,  I saw very little documentation of employing FFT for macroeconomic data. Can you please give sources to utilize FFT using time-series data in R? Thank you for your time.

Comment: You will not get the codez here. Search google for tutorial.

Comment: There are no solid tutorials for TS and FFT hence why I am here.

Comment: You won't find them here either. This is not a tutorial place. Come here if you have some code which has an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Don't waste your time with applying FFT's to macroeconomic data. If there are cycles in the data, then the only things to find is the fundamental frequency and probably a second harmonic. All else is noise.

An autocorrelation function is the (much) better tool here.

Comment: I have a number of ACF models that I use to forecast macroeconomic data but was hoping to explore other models. Thank you for your answer.